# After applying modifiers, I cannot select faces or edges

Tags: node-editor, faces, edges, selection-tools, select

I imported a .stl file into Blender and I edited it in the Geometry Node Editor.
I want to measure the area of certain faces, but I cannot see or select the faces or edges as before. Since the model changed significantly after my edits, is there a way to generate faces (essentially meshing triangular elements) and edges onto the new model?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If by applying you mean you just used modifiers, then this modifiers will not be visible in edit" mode unless:

- you apply the modifier with CTRL+A
- enable "display on edit mode in the options

[image]

[image]

But modifiers like the geometry nodes only allow you to edit the original object with display on edit mode enabled and not the final result.

[image]